# Press a button to carry out an async http get request and flash success on current page if successful (http.OK)

Tags: java, web-services, playframework

I have a button in play framework web app that links to a routes.Application.refresh
I need it to trigger a separate HTTP GET request say,

```
http://somehost/restful/refresh?id=123
```

If the GET request results in a success/200 response, then flash a success note onto the current page where the button we pressed lives. How can I do this?

Here is the **myapp.controller.Application.java** :-

```
public static Result refresh() {

    flash("success", "cache refreshed successfully on somehost");
    return GO_HOME  ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The flash part is not really that interesting when doing ajax, it is more for full page reload and then showing it in a play template.

Normally you would write a js callback in your ajax logic that will react on a success (or error) and shows the ui-component that you want the user to get as feedback. This can be done in a million ways, one example would be using jquery.